# Add Values to dropdownlist on the basis of SQL Query

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2005, drop-down-menu

I have a `dropdownlist` whose values are binded by a query which is

```
select emp_card_no, 
       emp_name + '-' 
                + cast(emp_card_no as varchar) 
                + '(' 
                + datename(MM,a.dt_of_leave) 
                + ' - ' 
                + cast(year(a.dt_of_leave)as varchar)
                +')' emp_name 
from emp_mst a 
where month(a.dt_of_leave) >= month(getdate())-1  
  and year(a.dt_of_leave) = 
        case when month(getdate())=1 then year(getdate())-1 
             else year(getdate()) 
        end
order by emp_name
```

whose results look something like this.

[![SQL output][1]][1]

Now what I want is, in `Emp_name` column, I want to add text as `PROCESS` OR `PENDING` after `(April - 2016)` on the basis of  query  which is below

```
select emp_mkey, * from emp_mon_day
where emp_mkey = 312
 and month = 4
 and year = 2016
```

If query returns any result then `PROCESS` otherwise `PENDING`.

**NOTE**

1st query column `Emp_card_no` is the `Emp_mkey` in `emp_mon_day` table.

Also see the code for binding dropdownlist

```
protected void funfillEmployee()
{
    DataTable DtCombo = new DataTable();
    string strdate = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

    DtCombo = ObjPriDal.ExecuteDataTable("select emp_card_no, emp_name + '-' + cast(emp_card_no as varchar)+ '(' + datename(MM,a.dt_of_leave)  + ' - ' + cast(year(a.dt_of_leave)as varchar)+')' emp_name  " +
                         "  from emp_mst a where month(a.dt_of_leave) >= month(getdate())-1  and  year(a.dt_of_leave)= case " +
                         "   when  month(getdate())=1 then year(getdate())-1 else year(getdate()) end order by emp_name ");

    cmbEmp_Name.DataTextField = "emp_name";
    cmbEmp_Name.DataValueField = "emp_card_no";
    cmbEmp_Name.DataSource = DtCombo;
    cmbEmp_Name.DataBind();
    cmbEmp_Name.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
    DtCombo.Clear();
}
```

Let me know how to do that.

I am using `SQL-server-2005`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
select a.emp_card_no, 
       a.emp_name + '-' 
                  + cast(a.emp_card_no as varchar) 
                  + '(' 
                  + datename(MM,a.dt_of_leave) 
                  + ' - ' 
                  + cast(year(a.dt_of_leave)as varchar)
                  +') '
                  +                
                    case when m.emp_mkey IS NULL 
                         then 'PENDING' 
                         else 'PROCESS' 
                    end                  
                  emp_name 
from emp_mst a 
LEFT JOIN emp_mon_day m ON m.Emp_mkey = a.Emp_card_no 
                        AND m.month = month(a.dt_of_leave) 
                        AND  m.year = year(a.dt_of_leave)
where month(a.dt_of_leave) >= month(getdate())-1  
  and year(a.dt_of_leave) = 
        case when month(getdate())=1 then year(getdate())-1 
             else year(getdate()) 
        end
order by emp_name
```

but you might have adapt that part

```
AND m.month = month(a.dt_of_leave) AND  m.year = year(a.dt_of_leave)
```

as month and year  are reserved words and I doubt you named your columns like this, but you did not specified other names

Comment: @coder ah yes you obviously missed to tell us that you had a 1-to-many relationship between the 2 tables. I assumed it it was 1-1. In order words you can have duplicate `Emp_mkey`  in your `emp_mon_day` table, right ?

Comment: @coder ok then 2 solutions because it's still too vague to give you a perfect answer: 1. if you can match the dates (year+ month) in your 2 tables, then add it in the `ON` clause : `LEFT JOIN emp_mon_day m ON m.Emp_mkey = a.Emp_card_no AND m.month = month(a.dt_of_leave) AND  m.year = year(a.dt_of_leave)`    2.otherwhise I'll propose you another aproach with a `NOT EXISTS` in your `SELECT`... try 1. and give feedback

Comment: let me know if u want from myside to clarify your doubts, if u need scripts of the table and any thing else to try with. I will give u. As I am still not getting ur point that what I have to do ??

Comment: The question is: do you want to check from the `emp_mon_day` table if a record exists for the same `Emp_card_no` **AND** same year/month, or do you just want to check if a record exists from the same `Emp_card_no` ? If 1 adapt the `LEFT JOIN` with the one in my previous comment, if 2 I'll provide you with another query

Comment: Yes, I want to check for the same year/month from `emp_mon_day` on that basis my `PROCESS` and `PENDING` logic will work. let me know if any else doubt is their

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109309/discussion-between-coder-and-thomas-g).

Comment: hi thomas, are you their ? need one small help here. let me know when u come